# Dead Partition Recovery?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I have a hard drive that seems to have lost it's partition.  Everything is wanting to just recover "RAW" data which, if I understand RAW data accurately that does me no good as I need to recover the folder structure & hierarchy as well.

I ran TestDisk and it shows me this image (well I can't post the image as my rep is to low :( --).  My question being is since this shows (or at least I think it does) the start & end sectors for the partition, could I re-create the FAT32 partition and the data still be intact?

Comment: There are utilities out there that will locate a suspected partition table and try to rebuild it for you.  Norton long ago used to do a decent job of it, I've been out of the repair business far too long to know what is a good tool to do this with today.

Comment: @Optichip I have tried multiple programs and most of them can see the partition but have not been able to succesfully recover it.  I wasn't sure if their is one program that is always succesful or if I could use the start & end information to "rebuild" the partition on my own.

Comment: If you know how to rebuild a partition table, and you know the boundaries of the partition you could be able to build it.  As always this is a touchy situation as one wrong move could wipe everything.

Comment: @Optichip I don't, I was just going to follow the data given by TestDisk - but if it is advanced i'll wait to see other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) I'm sure will help you here. It's an awesome tool and at the very least using [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) will enable you to get your files back (albeit not in their original structure). Testdisk on the other hand should be able to get you the files and their original structure.

You should have a look through the [Testdisk docs](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) but in essence once you've selected your device, selected the file system type (leave the default one testdisk allocates) you need to analyse your drive (run a quick and if needed 'deep' search on the partition) and then you can write the output of the partition structure to the drive which essentially restores the file system that was there previously.

It may be that you want to just recover the files and be done with the drive, in which case once you've searched for your lost partition you can select the option to "list" files and then copy them to another location.

If you get stuck with Testdisk the forum is excellent and often answered by the author of the software, Christophe Grenier, although there are users on here for sure that can help, myself included :-)

Answer (score 0):

try GetDataBack. It has version for FAT32 and NTFS too. SpinRite also comes to my mind and it can fix a lot of types of disk damage and is file system independent, but it is not free.